# "tar czf file.tar.gz dirname" or "tar -czf file.tar.gz dirname"?

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I always use `tar czf file.tar.gz dirname` instead of `tar -czf file.tar.gz dirname` (without `-`) because faster

I know... from the documentation, what I'm doing is wrong.

But what is the effect of my command?

(so far, I dont see any problem of my command... sometime I think why the documentation suggest `tar -czf file.tar.gz dirname` instead of `tar czf file.tar.gz dirname`?)

Answer (score 4):

It's all in the info pages:

“Like short options, "old options" are single letters. However, old options must be written together as a single clumped set[...] this old style syntax makes it difficult to match option letters with their corresponding arguments, and is often confusing. In the command `tar cvbf 20 /dev/rmt0`, for example, `20` is the argument for `-b`, `/dev/rmt0` is the argument for `-f`, and `-v` does not have a corresponding argument. Even using short options like in `tar -c -v -b 20 -f /dev/rmt0` is clearer, putting all arguments next to the option they pertain to.”

And you don't want to confuse your users, do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man tar
```

> The bundled-arguments format is supported for **compatibility with historic
>   implementations**. It consists of an initial word (with no leading - character)
>   in which each character indicates an option. Arguments follow as separate
>   words. The order of the arguments must match the order of the corresponding
>   characters in the bundled command word. For example,

```
  tar tbf 32 file.tar
```

> specifies three flags t, b, and f. The b and f flags both require arguments,
>   so there must be two additional items on the command line. The 32 is the
>   argument to the b flag, and file.tar is the argument to the f flag.

Answer (score 0):

while @user502515 is right, I always use `tar cvf` and I hope @Captain is still using it as well. It's cleaner and if some users find it confusing they can go `man tar` and learn it.  I accept that the new syntax is more explicit, but the old one is beautiful and besides, it's fun to use syntax from 1979.